# Torque formula in Java?

Tags: java, formula, torque

I'm trying to calculate the torque in a java program but I having some problems on how to convert the formula to code

Here is the formula: [image]

and here is my code:

`torque = CYLINDER_LOAD_FACTOR * ( ( Math.pow( (displacement / numberOfCylinders), 2) *  Math.exp(TORQUE_CONSTANT) * 0.59 ) );`

Comment: Looks like you're supposed to raise to the power of 0.59 but you're multiplying by 0.59.

Answer (score 2):

This entire expression should be raised to the power of 0.59,

```
( Math.pow( (displacement / numberOfCylinders), 2) *  Math.exp(TORQUE_CONSTANT) )
```

but you're multiplying by that amount. Try the following:

```
torque = CYLINDER_LOAD_FACTOR * Math.pow( Math.pow( (displacement / numberOfCylinders), 2) *  Math.exp(TORQUE_CONSTANT), 0.59 );
```